# How to solve HttpURLConnection connect issue on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I am currently trying to do a post request practice on Android Studio. I have a button created and when the button is clicked it should get a number from a textview and pass it on as an argument to a URL and get a response.

I have learned how to do a post request on my own and my code works when I run it on Visual Studio Code.
However, when I run the same code on Android Studio, the connection does not happen.

Here is my code.

```
Button translate = findViewById(R.id.transButton);
        translate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                TextView postText = findViewById(R.id.postText);

                String number = result.getText().toString();

                String output = "";

                HttpURLConnection connection = null;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("some random url that i replaced with");

                    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset","UTF-8");
                    connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    connection.setDoInput(true);

                    connection.connect();

                    String parameters = "random parameters";
                    OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                            new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
                    writer.write(parameters);
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();
                    out.close();

                    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

                    if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                        output += "Status: True\n";
                        String line;
                        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            String[] list = line.split(",");
                            String[] message = list[2].split(":");
                            output += message[1];
                        }
                        reader.close();
                    }
                    else{
                        output += "Status: False\n";
                    }
                    postText.setText(output);

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setMessage(output);
                    builder.setTitle("Magic Number");
                    builder.setCancelable(true);
                    builder.setPositiveButton(
                            "Ok",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            }
                    );
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (connection != null) {
                        connection.disconnect();
                    }
                }


            }
        });
```

I have replaced the URL and parameters with random strings.

The issue occurs at the line `connection.connect()`. I tried tracing the issue by changing the textview text and found out the connect never occurred. Again if I run the exact same code on Visual Studio Code it will connect and I can fetch a response from the server, but `connect.connect()` doesn't seem to run on Android Studio.

And before anyone asks, I did give internet permission in my manifest file.

Comment: In Android, you can't run network request on main thread. Move all your network code to a background thread, like `AsyncTask`

Comment: I have seen that somewhere. But I cannot implement AsyncTask in the mainActivity class because it already implements AppCompatActivity. Do I create a different class or method and put the code in there? And how exactly would I do that? Thanks for the hjelp!

Comment: First off, don't use AsyncTask for this. Do research into actual HTTP libraries for Android like Volley or Okhttp

Comment: Try to practice using libraries like Retrofit for REST API calls in your project.

Comment: *What* issue occurs?